# JQuery: show div on radiobutton select

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I am trying to use jQuery to show a div when the user selects a particular radio button (`Other`) within a radiobutton group.

The html is below

```
<div id="countries">

<input id="Washington_D.C" type="radio" name="location" value="Washington">Washington D.C</input>
<input id="Other" type="radio" name="location" value="">Other</input>
    <div id="other locations" style="display: none">
    </div>
</div>
```

Using the JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("radio[@name='location']").change(function(){
        if ($("radio[@name='location']:checked").val() == 'Other')
        $("#county_drop_down").show();
    });
 });
```

But it's not showing the div other locations when I select the radiobutton `Other`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give it a value of `Other`.

Thus, not so

```
<input id="Other" TYPE="RADIO" NAME="location" VALUE="">Other</input>
```

but so

```
<input id="Other" TYPE="RADIO" NAME="location" VALUE="Other">Other</input>
```

At first glance, your jQuery code looks fine. I would however prefer `click` above `change`, since `change` doesn't get fired on 1st click if there's no means of preselection.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("radio[name='location']").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === 'Other')
    {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#county_drop_down").show();
        }
    }
});
```

set the radio button value to Other for this code to work.